# System.ArgumentException on putting AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer in Form

Tags: c#, exception, argumentexception, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a standard `Form` with only a `AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer` and no code except autogenerated. I get `System.ArgumentException` twice on every app start. It says, that object does not provide `IPropertyNotifySink` interface. But how to implement it, since I haven't got namespace, which contains it (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)? And what I have to do in implemented functions (`OnChanged(Int32)` and `OnRequestEdit(Int32)`)?

Comment: Did you change any properties or did you just add the component and debugged?

Comment: @VisualVincent Just added the component, nothing more.

Comment: Strange, what OS are you using?

Comment: @VisualVincent Windows 7.

Comment: What happens if you reset the list of exceptions to break on? `Debug > Windows > Exception Settings > Reset`?

Comment: @VisualVincent exactly the same.

Comment: And you have no specific line where the error is thrown?

Comment: It's in autogenerated line in Form1.Designer.cs: ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1)).EndInit();

Comment: [From what I've been able to find so far](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/816ef365-0d7b-4587-9959-1534b924bde0/source-object-does-not-expose-ipropertynotifysink-event-interface-error-only-when-debugging?forum=vsdebug) resetting the exceptions should fix the issue. Please make sure that `System.ArgumentException` isn't still checked when you reset.

Comment: @VisualVincent Isn't it a bad practice, ignoring exceptions? Also, it's unchecked, but I still see it in diagnostics panel.

Comment: You are not ignoring the exceptions, you are just ignoring those already handled by a `try/catch` block. The _unhandled exceptions_, which will cause your application to stop execution, will still be thrown.

Comment: At the moment I cannot find or come up with anything more for you to try. And as I've never experienced the exception myself I will not be able to try it. I'm afraid I can't do much more at this point. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal mishap.  A well-behaved ActiveX object ought to implement the IPropertyNotifySink interface (an *unmanaged* COM interface) but it is not required to do so.  The AxHost wrapper class just blindly assumes it does, so tries to subscribe it, but the internal ConnectionContainer constructor discovers that it doesn't.

Which is *not* fatal, since implementing the interface is optional, AxHost calls the constructor with the *throwException* argument set to false.  So you see the first-chance exception raised in the debugger but then it catches it again and returns.  Fwiw, that code could have very easily been written so you'd never see the exception at all, but the Microsoft programmer took a shortcut with a catch-em-all exception handler.  Just annoying, that's all.

It is definitely *not* your job to implement the interface, it is control's job.  So trying to implement OnChanged() and OnRequestEdit() doesn't make sense.

Just keep motoring, you don't have a real problem.

Comment: And what this interface was originally created for?

Comment: To allow an ActiveX host to report changes to stock properties that have ambient behavior.  The Font property would be a standard example, a control normally uses the same font as its parent.  BackColor is another one.  Doesn't apply to WMP, it is not the kind of control that behaves like the ones you find back in the WPF or Winforms toolbox.